# A question on vertical tangent(computing the value of a limit expression)

Tags: calculus

[image: graph of y = x^(2/3) - (x-1)^(1/3)]

I am studying about the concept of vertical tangents, and I have a problem.
I need to figure out if the function $y = x^{2/3} - (x-1)^{1/3}$ has a vertical tangent at $x=1$.
I tried to find out the derivative at $x=1$ as below.
$$\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{(1+h)^{2/3}-h^{1/3}-1}{h}$$
However, I cannot decide if the derivative is the $+\infty$ or the $-\infty$.
Could anyone help me find out the correct value of the derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your picture and your algebra show that this function is not differentiable at $0$. The derivative is neither $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Geometrically, that point is a *cusp*. Whether or not it has a "vertical tangent" there will depend on a precise definition of that term.

Comment: My definition of the vertical tangent is as follows:
We say that the curve $y=f(x)$ has a vertical tangent at the point where $x=x_0$ if 
$$\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=\infty or -\infty$$
Could you help me compute the value of the limit expression?

Comment: You have mixed up two ways to write the slope of a secant. One uses $x$ and $x+h$, the other uses $x$ and $x_0$. When you get it right you will see that in your example the limit from the right is $\infty$ and from the left is $-\infty$. So there is no vertical tangent there according to your definition.